# turf.js / turf.buffer and Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, turfjs

I have a simple Google Map. I've added a marker at a given lat, lng.

I want to use turf.js to calculate a 1km buffer which I can then display as a Google Maps polygon.

The path that turf.buffer() returns is an ellipse. The distance from the marker to the boundary is correct latitudinally. However it is short of 1km longitudinally. It looks like there is a problem with the projection, however both the Google Maps API and turf.js documents state WGS84 is the default projection.

[image]

The end game is using turf.js to buffer Points, Polylines and Polygons so I can't just draw a Google Maps circle as a workaround unfortunately. I would consider migrating to Leaflet, however we are already quite invested in developing for the Google Maps API

I've created an htm file [here](http://gmwildlife.org.uk/zz-playground/index.htm) showing the problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going nuts. The buffer isnt geodesic so at the equator you get a round buffer and as you move north or south your buffer becomes squashed longitudinally towards the poles. The turf.js team are aware. See https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/110 for full details.

I'm looking at using clipper.js instead. This is a cartesian library (2d) so in the uk i can use osgb eastings and northings. I will also have to flip north and south as clipper assumes we are dealing with standard graphics i.e. The y axis is inverted like in css with 0,0 being the top left.

Im going to use geotools to transform between osgb and wgs.

Comment: It is fixed now, as explained on this post https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/pull/718